# Assign a name to a cell based on 4 possibilities in another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm quite new to conditional formatting in excel. I'm looking for a way to fill a cell based on multiple choices. Here is an example:

I have a list of provinces, and next to each province, I have a "1" if the province is in a rural setting, remote area etc.

[image]

In another sheet, I have the names of each province, and the aim is summarise the information and make appear in the column "archetype" the type of each province (rural, remote etc). So far I've been trying multiple "if" functions, but it is leading me nowhere.

[image]

Comment: Can a province have one archetype or multiple?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio, just one

Comment: conditional formatting is only used to change the appearance of a cell, not its content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XLOOKUP for this. The inner XLOOKUP will return a four-item array of 0s or 1s for the row relating to the province specified on the current row. The outer XLOOKUP will search that four-item array for a 1 and return the text from row 1 which corresponds to that position in the array.

```
=XLOOKUP(1,XLOOKUP(A15,A2:A12,B2:E12),$B$1:$E$1)
```

[image]

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. Such a great input, many thanks